# Setting Visual Studio TFS timeout

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I would like to manually set a timeout for Visual Studio when connecting to TFS or TFS / VSO online.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

The reason for this is that my work PC disconnects from VSO periodically (every time I lock it and Direct Access severs my connection) and when I then try to perform any actions check outs/ins etc it takes 30-60 seconds or so before timing out, during which time it locks up the VS UI thread. No matter how many times I try to reconnect it won't until I restart VS.

I can normally tell within 2-3 seconds if this is going to happen and it has become quicker for me end the task in Visual Studio & start it up again.

As a result I would like to be able to set a timeout of say 5 seconds and if I can't get a VSO connection in this timeframe at least I can close and open VS rather than ending the task through task manager.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can follow the steps below to set the time out on your PC:

1. Open Registry Editor.
2. Go to `HEKY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\RequestSettings`.

   (If `RequestSettings` key does not exist, you can right click on
   `TeamFoundation` and create a new one)
3. Modify the value of `DefaultTimeout`. (The time is in milliseconds)
   [image]

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT what type would the DefaultTimeout be? DWord-32?

Comment: @jessehouwing Yes, DWORD 32.